# Unusual data grouping / transformation

Tags: javascript, php, algorithm, grouping, transformation

I'm struggling with an algorithmic problem how go transform or group data to get specified output.

My input is a bunch of messages in given order (from newest to oldest):

```json
[
   {
      "id":5,
      "created_at":"2021-01-01 00:00:00",
      "message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...",
      "is_author":true,
      "meta_data":{
         
      }
   },
   {
      "id":4,
      "created_at":"2021-01-01 01:00:00",
      "message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...",
      "is_author":true,
      "meta_data":{
         
      }
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "created_at":"2021-01-01 03:00:00",
      "message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...",
      "is_author":false,
      "meta_data":{
         
      }
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "created_at":"2021-01-01 04:00:00",
      "message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...",
      "is_author":false,
      "meta_data":{
         
      }
   },
   {
      "id":1,
      "created_at":"2021-01-01 05:00:00",
      "message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...",
      "is_author":true,
      "meta_data":{
         
      }
   },
   {
      "id":0,
      "created_at":"2021-01-01 06:00:00",
      "message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...",
      "is_author":false,
      "meta_data":{
         
      }
   }
]
```

Desired output after transformation:

```json
[
   {
      "is_author":true,
      "messages":[
         {
            "id":5,
            "created_at":"2021-01-01 00:00:00",
            "message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...",
            "meta_data":{
               
            }
         },
         {
            "id":4,
            "created_at":"2021-01-01 01:00:00",
            "message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...",
            "meta_data":{
               
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "is_author":false,
      "messages":[
         {
            "id":3,
            "created_at":"2021-01-01 03:00:00",
            "message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...",
            "meta_data":{
               
            }
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "created_at":"2021-01-01 04:00:00",
            "message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...",
            "meta_data":{
               
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "is_author":true,
      "messages":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "created_at":"2021-01-01 05:00:00",
            "message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...",
            "meta_data":{
               
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "is_author":false,
      "messages":[
         {
            "id":0,
            "created_at":"2021-01-01 06:00:00",
            "message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...",
            "meta_data":{
               
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

So as you can see, each occurrence of the **is_author** parameter creates a new group that collects messages from this author ?

Is there any efficient solution in JS or PHP to transform such data?

Comment: created date are same for all records, is_author can only form 2 groups at max, then which basis you are going to form group?

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? Please share your code / ideas.

Comment: @navnath dates are different, please take a look a the time value; is_author is only a divder which starts a new group

Comment: but `id: 3` and `id:2` have different time then why in same group?

Comment: @MrSmith42 my first idea was to foreach elements and create new object when is_author changes, in second, third etc. run of the loop I would check if last created object has the same value of is_author, if so.. then push new messages into it. But it can't get it working

Comment: @navnath, yep but as it's said.. each new occurrence of the is_author creates new group.. may be some real life example

I've got given input and my goal is to display messages in order by date and grouped by author, just like messages in Messenger does

Comment: @Alex Oraniewsky: "But it can't get it working". So start debugging, post your code and debug information and lets find out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's much to be said for abstracting a bit.  Here, we want to split our array up whenever something changes between two consecutive elements.  That is the fundamental grouping, and if we think about it that way, we can layer the gathering of them into a single `{is_author, messages}` object on top of that grouping.

So we might write a generic function that splits our data into subarrays whenever some function of the previous and current items returns `true`.  Then our main function would call that, passing a function that tests whether the `is_author` property is different, then reformat the generated groups after it returns.  It could look like this:

```js
const splitWhenever = (pred) => (xs) =>
  xs .length == 0 ? [] : xs .slice (1) .reduce (
    ((xss, x, i) => pred (xs [i], x) 
       ? [...xss, [x]] 
       : [...xss .slice (0, -1), [... xss [xss .length - 1], x]]
    ), [[xs [0]]]
  )

const transform = (input) => splitWhenever ((x, y) => x.is_author != y.is_author) (input)
  .map ((xs => ({
    is_author: xs [0] .is_author, 
    messages: xs .map (({is_author, ...rest}) => rest)
  })))

const input = [{id: 5, created_at: "2021-01-01 00:00:00", message: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...", is_author: true, meta_data: {}}, {id: 4, created_at: "2021-01-01 01:00:00", message: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...", is_author: true, meta_data: {}}, {id: 3, created_at: "2021-01-01 03:00:00", message: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...", is_author: false, meta_data: {}}, {id: 2, created_at: "2021-01-01 04:00:00", message: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...", is_author: false, meta_data: {}}, {id: 1, created_at: "2021-01-01 05:00:00", message: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...", is_author: true, meta_data: {}}, {id: 0, created_at: "2021-01-01 06:00:00", message: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...", is_author: false, meta_data: {}}]

console .log (transform (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

This is more complex than the answer from navnath.  But it builds on `splitWherever`, which is now reusable across this and other programs.

In a followup to navnath's answer, the OP asks, "[W]hat if I have processed a set of data and the application loads new data [...]  will it be possible to join the messages from the object id 6 to the existing group?"  I commented there with a suggested change to do that with only minor tweaks to navanth's code.  But after rereading, I think that this new data was supposed to come before the existing data.(Because the existing ids are sorted descending and the new ones are larger than those.)  That means that my suggestion there would probably not do.

Here it takes a bit more work, as we have already split apart the grouping from the reformatting.  This version, which still uses the same generic `splitWhenever`, will first flatten the existing structure back into the original format, prepend the new data, then run all over again.  This may sound wasteful.  Perhaps it is.  Better might be to simply keep the original list, prepend to that and then rerun the approach above.  But since our transformation is reversible, this will work if it's desired:

```js
const splitWhenever = (fn) => (xs) =>
  xs .length == 0 ? [] : xs .slice (1) .reduce (
    ((xss, x, i) => fn (xs [i], x) 
       ? [...xss, [x]] 
       : [...xss .slice (0, -1), [... xss [xss .length - 1], x]]
    ), [[xs [0]]]
  )

const transform = (input, old = []) => splitWhenever ((x, y) => x.is_author != y.is_author) ([
  ...input, 
  ...old.flatMap (({is_author, messages}) => messages .map (msg => ({...msg, is_author})))
]).map ((xs => ({
  is_author: xs [0] .is_author, 
  messages: xs .map (({is_author, ...rest}) => rest)
})))

const input = [{id: 5, created_at: "2021-01-01 00:00:00", message: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...", is_author: true, meta_data: {}}, {id: 4, created_at: "2021-01-01 01:00:00", message: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...", is_author: true, meta_data: {}}, {id: 3, created_at: "2021-01-01 03:00:00", message: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...", is_author: false, meta_data: {}}, {id: 2, created_at: "2021-01-01 04:00:00", message: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...", is_author: false, meta_data: {}}, {id: 1, created_at: "2021-01-01 05:00:00", message: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...", is_author: true, meta_data: {}}, {id: 0, created_at: "2021-01-01 06:00:00", message: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...", is_author: false, meta_data: {}}]
const result = transform (input)
console .log ('Original data')
console .log (result)

const additional = [{id: 7, created_at: "2020-12-31 22:00:00", message: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...", is_author: false, meta_data: {}}, {id: 6, created_at: "2020-12-31 22:00:00", message: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...", is_author: true, meta_data: {}}]
const result2 = transform (additional, result)
console .log ('With additional results')
console .log (result2)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Comment: By looking at it looks difficult but I would say it's just awesome.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data=[{"id":5,"created_at":"2021-01-01 00:00:00","message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...","is_author":true,"meta_data":{}},{"id":4,"created_at":"2021-01-01 01:00:00","message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...","is_author":true,"meta_data":{}},{"id":3,"created_at":"2021-01-01 03:00:00","message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...","is_author":false,"meta_data":{}},{"id":2,"created_at":"2021-01-01 04:00:00","message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...","is_author":false,"meta_data":{}},{"id":1,"created_at":"2021-01-01 05:00:00","message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...","is_author":true,"meta_data":{}},{"id":0,"created_at":"2021-01-01 06:00:00","message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...","is_author":false,"meta_data":{}}];

const result = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const { is_author, ...rest } = item;
  // if is_author match with previous object
  if(acc.length && acc[acc.length-1].is_author === is_author){
    // copy previous messages, along with current item
    acc[acc.length-1].messages = [...acc[acc.length-1].messages, rest ];
  }else{
      acc.push({ is_author, messages: [ rest ] });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Comment: @Alex Oraniewsky Is this what you need? but it's not related to date, it's related to is_author, whenever the is_author chain breaks new group will be created.

Comment: wow works like a charm ! great ! I just need to study to know how does it work

Comment: see the comments, let me know what you didnt understand

Comment: one more thing.. what if I have processed a set of data and the application loads new data (id: 6, id: 7 etc.)
for example, in case when id: 5 had the attribute is_author = true and the newly added id: 6 also has the attribute is_author = true, will it be possible to join the messages from the object id 6 to the existing group?

Comment: yes, test with above code

Comment: Hey Update your question. since it's not group by date, its only group by `is_author` untill `is_author` value change breaks the chain

Comment: thank you, I've edited this question...

Comment: I'm trying to add this set to exiting result :  const data2=[{"id":6,"created_at":"2021-01-01 08:00:00","message":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...","is_author":false,"meta_data":{}}];
  but is doesn't merge well

Comment: It should be in new group right? because its `is_author` is false

Comment: If you want to be able to make this dynamic, try `const transform = (data, start = []) => data.reduce((acc, item) => { /* existing code */ }, start)`.  Then `const result = transform (data)`.  And later when you have additional data, `const newResult = transform (additional, result)`.

Comment: Looking at this again, my previous comment is probably not right.  If you were appending the new data to the list, then this would be great.  But it looks as though you want to prepend it.  If that's the case, then you might look at the technique in my answer to flatten back to the original list, then prepend and run again.  (Or simply keep the original list around, prepend to it, and run again.)

Comment: Yeah right, that makes sense.

Comment: @ScottSauyet thank you for your contribution, for your knowledge and your precious time - it's amazing !